# Custom JQuery deferred handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

not sure if this is possible but I'll give it a go. I've got a deferred function that makes a call of to the server to either create or update and object. for example:

```
var createOrUpdate = function(item) {
    var self = this;
    var deferred;

    if (item.id && item.id > 0) {
        updated = true;
        deferred = update.call(self, params);
    } else {
        deferred = create.call(self);
    }

    return deferred;
};
```

where the create and call methods return deferred of themselves. This will allow me to call

```
foo.createOrUpdate(bar).then(function(response) {
    // something happened
});
```

However I'd like to be able to add in some custom deferred handlers so that I could do this

```
foo.createOrUpdate(bar).created(function(response) {
    // an item was created
}).updated(function(response) {
    //an item was updated
});
```

Firstly, is this possible. And secondly, if so, how would I go about it.

basically I want to create a custom deferred handler.

Many thanks.

Comment: you will have to implement that yourself.

Comment: I understand that. That's what I'm looking to do. And was hoping for some pointers :D

Comment: What would `.created()` and `.updated()` do for you that `.progress()`, `.done()`, `.fail()` or `.then()` do not already do? I suggest you need to arrange for `create()` and `update()` functions to resolve their respective Deferreds with some value (or property of an object) that identifies which action ('create' or 'update') has successfully completed. Why make things more complicated?

Answer (score 1):

Not really tested:

```
var createOrUpdate = function(item) {
  return {
    isUpdated : item.id && item.id > 0,
    created   : function(cb) {
      if (! this.isUpdated)
        create.call(self).then(cb);
      return this;
    },  
    updated   : function(cb) {
      if (this.isUpdated)
        update.call(self, params).then(cb);
      return this;
    }   
  };  
};  

foo.createOrUpdate(bar)
  .created(function(response) {
    // an item was created
  })
  .updated(function(response) {
    //an item was updated
  });
```

Comment: It just twigged for me whilst I was driving home. Thats's pretty much where I was heading. Looks right but I'll check in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to make your own `$.Deferred` objects, and use `.resolve` to send a param that says which method it is.

For example:

```
function create(){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred;

    $.post('/your/AJAX/call', {your: data}, function(retData){
        deferred.resolve('create', retData);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}

function update(params){
    var deferred = new $.Deferred;

    $.post('/your/AJAX/call', {your: data, also: params}, function(retData){
        deferred.resolve('update', retData);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Keeping your `createOrUpdate` the same, you can use `.then`, and you will be passed both params from the `.resolve`.

```
foo.createOrUpdate(bar).then(function(method, response) {
    switch(method){
        case 'update':
            break;
        case 'create':
            break;
    }
});
```

Here's a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/U5jyJ/